# Cannot npm install for angular-phonecat tutorial : Cannot find module 'update-notifier'

Tags: node.js, angularjs, path, npm

I am having issues running npm install in the angular-phonecat directory. I am assuming this may be an issue with my paths but not sure. Any insight would be much appreciated. I keep getting Error: Cannot find module 'update-notifier'. If i install this individually i will just get another missing module.

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node

$ which npm
/Users/Ashton/.node/bin/npm
```

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/node:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"
```

```
$ npm install

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall /Users/Ashton/Dropbox/Learning Projects/angular-phonecat
> bower install


module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'update-notifier'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (/Users/Ashton/Dropbox/Learning Projects/angular-phonecat/node_modules/.bin/bower:8:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/Users/Ashton/.node/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Ashton/Dropbox/Learning Projects/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Ashton/Dropbox/Learning Projects/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Do you have bower installed in your machine?

Comment: yes... $ which bower
/Users/Ashton/.node/bin/bower

Comment: What if you do npm install update-notifier?

Comment: Then i get "Error: Cannot find module 'bower-logger'". I feel like i should not have to install these dependencies one by one... am I wrong? Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: If you are getting these errors then you have to install all these dependencies in order to work

Comment: After I install a few more I get: "Error: Cannot find module '../lib'" and this one cannot be installed " ERROR: Repository not found.". I feel like I have had this issue before and it was due to npm installing into a stange directory but I am not sure how to debug or resolve.

Comment: FYI. I re-pulled the repo into another directory and it installed find. Maybe that on e just got corrupt somehow but the new directory works fine.

Comment: Global installs on Unix systems go to {prefix}/lib/node_modules. Global installs on Windows go to {prefix}/node_modules (that is, no lib folder.)

Comment: you can also get this error if the port is already in use.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue when I was trying to download angular-seed project on windows 10. I installed GIT command line. Then Instead of downloading the ZIP, I used GIT command line to download the project. git clone https://YOURPORJECT.For the network issue I typed in git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://.