# npm install / bower install issue and deprecated modules with angular-phonecat setup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, macos, bower

I am trying to run `npm install` on my terminal as part of the setup for angular-phonecat as per the instructions on https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

When I run the command I am getting issues with deprecated modules and errors when reaching the bower install section.

Does anybody know how I can update the deprecated modules to avoid the warnings and how I can fix the bower errors?

Here is the output I am receiving:

```
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
-
> fsevents@1.0.14 install /Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v46-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall /Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat
> bower install

bower EACCES        EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/Eamon/.cache/bower/registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/jquery_d223e'

Stack trace:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/Eamon/.cache/bower/registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/jquery_d223e'
    at Error (native)

Console trace:
Error
    at StandardRenderer.error (/Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:81:37)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:110:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Logger.emit (/Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:48:20
    at _rejected (/Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
    at /Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
    at Promise.when (/Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
System info:
Bower version: 1.7.9
Node version: 4.4.0
OS: Darwin 15.6.0 x64

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-phonecat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Eamon/Documents/Scripting/Web Development/Learning/Javascript/Angularjs/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried searching on other posts with similar issues but none of these have helped me find a solution:

- [error when npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866385/error-when-npm-install)
- [Got an error while running "npm install" on angular-phonecat directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591714/got-an-error-while-running-npm-install-on-angular-phonecat-directory)
- [Cannot npm install for angular-phonecat tutorial : Cannot find module 'update-notifier'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259317/cannot-npm-install-for-angular-phonecat-tutorial-cannot-find-module-update-no)

I have also tried running `sudo npm install` with the same issue. I have a feeling the bower install issues are due to the setup of the bower cache looking at the error output but I am not 100% certain.

Has anyone encountered similar issues when setting up the installation for angular-phonecat?

Any help would be greatly welcomed.

Many Thanks,
Eamon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ISSUE**: You (the user) don't have the right set of permissions for the directory.

The instant way out is to run the npm install using sudo, but this may give you the same error, or improper installation.

AND changing directory ownership is not a good option, a temporary patch. I am answering the question, as I feel I have a more elegant solution/suggestion to the problem. I came across same issues multiple times i.e. 'npm install -g @angular/cli'.

Uninstalled the package and executed the following commands (in the order mentioned) to have clean installation.

---

**Solution**/**Suggestion**: Change npm's Default Directory (from official [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-two-change-npms-default-directory))

Back-up your computer before moving forward.

(optional) In case you have a erroneous installation, first uninstall it:

```
npm uninstall <package-name>  # use sudo if you used it while installation
npm cache verify  # or, npm cache clean for npm version below 5.x.x
```

1. Make a directory for global installations:

   **`mkdir ~/.npm-global`**
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   **`npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`**
3. Open or create a `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` file and add this line:

   **`export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`**
4. Back on the command line, update your system variables, or restart the terminal:

   **`source ~/.profile`**
5. (optional) Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.

   **`npm install -g jshint`**

Answer (score 0):

Having looked into this it appears that bower was having issues with permissions and was resolved by running the bower install separately using sudo:

```
sudo bower install --allow-root
```

However, you should not use sudo with bower. It is likely that if you have to then the ~/.cache has been set incorrectly either by installing using sudo or installing your first package via sudo. More info about this can be found here: http://www.competa.com/blog/2014/12/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/

Instead you should rectify the ownership by running the following:

```
sudo chown -R $user ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $user ~/.config
```

To find your user you can simply run the following command on the command line:

```
$ whoami
```

If you want to open to a wider group you can also add a group to the chown command. To find out which group your user belongs to you can type the following command:

```
$ groups
```

To set the group at the same time as the user simply change the command to the following and replace $user and $group with your desired user and group:

```
sudo chown -R $user:$group ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $user:$group ~/.config
```

If you are seeing an issue like one of the below when running a bower install during your npm install:

```
EACCES: permission denied, open '/some/directory'
EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/some/directory'
```

You will need to change the permissions to the folder containing the file to be your user by doing:

```
sudo chown -R USER /some/directory
```

Just change the folder that the file is stored in, not the file itself. When you run `npm install` after this it will work if it needs to install any bower components that are having issues installing while using your current user and not using `sudo`.

Thanks,
Eamon